# Troubleshooting a stuck fermentation with Ringwood Ale

Tags: yeast, troubleshooting, stuck-fermentation, attenuation, primary-fermentation

I'm brewing an IPA using Wyeast 1187 (Ringwood Ale) and it seems stuck.  I'm brewing 19L (5G) with an OG of 1.052 and pitched two (smacked) smackpacks of 1187 straight into the primary bucket.  I used a 1/2 tsp of Wyeast nutrient in the boil, too.  Temperature has been pretty even between 19-22C.

I had about 24 hours lag time before any activity, followed by furious fermentation for about 24 hours and then bubbling stopped.  It's now 5 days later and gravity is 1.026.  I'm only expecting 70% or so attenuation from using Ringwood but this seems well under (50%?).

I feel like I've done everything right (sufficient pitch rate, with nutrient, ideal temp) yet have got such a poor attenuation.  What went wrong?  Can I get it started again?

Answer (score 2):

That yeast needs a lot of O2 at pitching and rousing during fermentation.  Add to that the fact that it's only been 5 days.  Baby it along for another 2 weeks.  It could also be dependent on your recipe.